# How to fetch and upload data in php mysql server in android application?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, android-sqlite

I want to develop an application that fetch text and image and store text and image in MySQL database from Php server so I am confuse about parsing data from the server and upload data to server so which parsing method is useful for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) is the best I have ever found for this type of requirement.

You need to use a Php Webservice that handles the request from the mobile application. A Json data format is used to do transaction between mobile application and web service.

Comment: if i want to do it with xml parsing then which method is useful because my application is related to one time fetching and if new values found then it download again..

Comment: @PranavLathigara XmlPullParser is there for it.

Comment: have u any example or link for it